# numpy where on non-sorted array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to find the indices of the elements in a numpy array which matches a list. My array is not sorted. As of now, I am using the below code

```
Y = np.array([ 2,2,1,1,3,1,3,2,-1,-1])
indcs = [np.where(Y == c)[0] for c in range(1,4)]
```

> indcs
>
> [array([2, 3, 5]), array([0, 1, 7]), array([4, 6])]

But I feel like there will be a better approach to get the result for each value to be searched as rows than simply iterating using a for loop. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try `numpy.isin`, it might be helpful to get full list of indices (but not list of arrays).

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you.

```
    indices=[i for i,v in enumerate(Y.tolist()) if v in range(0,4)]
```